# How to throw a custom error from a dart extension dll?

Tags: c, dll, dart, dart-native-extension

I am trying to create an extension to wrap an existing DLL without extensive knowledge of C/++. I have used the [sample extension](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/) as a base and everything seems to work fine, what I would like to do is have some error handling inside my dll.

Is there a way of sending custom errors back to dart if something inside the dll fails? Would it just be a case of sending lets say an array with the first parameter being a bool as to whether it failed or not and the second parameter being a string for the error if there is one. Or is there an actual way to throw errors from the dll itself?

Hope this made sense,
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look inside `dart_api.h` file, it contains a lot of comments about Dart native stuff.

I have found `Dart_ThrowException` function there, but also a comment saying that `Dart_NewUnhandledExceptionError` should be used instead.

Both functions need a Dart exception object handle. It seems that Dart team uses their own [Dart Util library](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/runtime/bin/dartutils.cc) to create them:

```
Dart_ThrowException(DartUtils::NewDartArgumentError("error message"))
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark this as the answer. I dug around their util library and extracted the functions I required to create a custom exception. It basically involved creating a new instance of my exception class and sending it to dart. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: It seems like `Dart_ThrowException` will be removed in the future and the recommended way is using `Dart_NewUnhandledExceptionError` to create the Exception object and then using `Dart_PropagateError` to propagate it back to Dart.